# How can I generate array combinations such that so two elements in the array can not be together in any of combinations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose, I have an array of five elements `['a','b','c','d','e']`. I want combinations of four elements but I want that `'a'` and `'b'` **not be together in any of combinations**. How would I do that?

Expected result should be 
`['a', 'c', 'd', 'e']`
`['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`

Please write a more generalize solution.I am using ruby's `combination` method.I here just write an example.It may be possible that the combination number may vary(like there may be a array of 9 with size of 7 combinations) and also It may needed that I want two elements say `a` and `e` and `d` and `f` should not be together in any of combination.I know it bit confusing please let me know if I need to explain.Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: does elements order make sense in this combinations?

Comment: @mmichael I have simply added code inside the combination block and iterate through each element with `each` method and I reject one of the two element I dont want together

Comment: @lx00st No But the combinations must be unique means.

Answer (score 2):

```
['a','b','c','d','e'].permutation(4).reject do |e| 
  e.include?('a') && e.include?('b')
end
```

Or, if you do not care about element order (credits to @mark-thomas,) use [`Array#combination`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-combination):

```
['a','b','c','d','e'].combination(4).reject do |e| 
  e.include?('a') && e.include?('b')
end
#⇒ [["a", "c", "d", "e"], ["b", "c", "d", "e"]]
```

Please note, this approach is eager to resources. I’dn’t recommend to use it on big arrays.

Comment: Good, but if element order does not matter, use `combination` instead of `permutation`

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for something like that:

```
def combine(array, should_not_be_together, size)
  aux          = []
  add_together = true

  while aux.size < size
    random = Random.rand(2)
    if random == 1
      aux << array.sample
    elsif add_together
      aux << should_not_be_together.sample
      add_together = false
    end

    aux.uniq!
  end

  aux
end

array                  = ['c', 'd', 'e']
should_not_be_together = ['a', 'b']
size                   = 4
combine(array, should_not_be_together, size)
```

Results:

```
# => ["c", "a", "d", "e"]
# => ["e", "b", "c", "d"]
# => ["e", "a", "c", "d"]
# => ["c", "d", "b", "e"]
# => ["d", "b", "e", "c"]
# => ["a", "c", "e", "d"]
# => ["c", "b", "d", "e"]
# => ["c", "a", "e", "d"]
```

Comment: What happened with obviously needed `["b", "c", "e", "d"]`?